# How can my data object reject changes from a databound control? (Control is not displaying actual value)

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, data-binding

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I just don't see it.  Any advice is appreciated!

I have a Property in my DO (data object representing a hardware device) that is bound to a Control (combobox, binding "Text" property) in my form.  If the user types an invalid value, my property's Set{} rejects the change and sets the corresponding private value to something valid.

If the public property gets read by the control, it would read the right value, but it's not doing that.  It continues to show the invalid value that the user entered.

I don't think I can use the regular databinding "validation" because those work on the control itself, and the Form is unaware of what the value limits should be (am I wrong?).  Only the data object knows its limits (could change based on the selected hardware device's version, units-of-measure selected, etc.).

I suppose I could use a masked textbox and bind its min/max to two more properties in the data object, but that seems hokey, and I'd like to use the combobox so users can select common values instead of always typing.

How can I get my Control to refresh its value after it tries to update the DO property?

In Form:

```
    comboBox_Speed.DataBindings.Add("Text", testProgramObject, "SpeedSetting", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    comboBox_Speed.DataBindings["Text"].ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    comboBox_Speed.DataBindings["Text"].Format += new ConvertEventHandler(DeviceClass.DisplayInSelectedUnits);
    comboBox_Speed.DataBindings["Text"].Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(DeviceClass.StoreInDatabaseUnits);
```

In Data Object:

```
    private UInt16 _speedSetting = 0;
    public Double SpeedSetting{
        get { return _speedSetting ; }
        set
        {
            double temp = value; //databinding Parse function requires type Double for its destination.
            try { _speedSetting = Convert.ToUInt16(temp); } // maybe user typed number too big for UInt16
            catch
            {
                //_speedSetting= 0; // <-- Does not cause Control to display this value. It keeps invalid value.
                SpeedSetting= 0; // <-- I thought this would trigger the control to read the changed value, but it doesn't.
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SpeedSetting"); 
        } 
    }
```

THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try TextUpdate event.

```
comboBox_Speed.TextUpdate += new EventHandler(comboBox_Speed_TextUpdate);

void comboBox_Speed_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox_Speed.DataBindings["Text"].WriteValue();
        comboBox_Speed.DataBindings["Text"].ReadValue();
    }
```

Comment: While this works, and does so immediately, it causes another problem.  The cursor gets reset to position 0 every time the property value gets read (which is every time the user changes the text). This makes causes the number to appear to type backwards.

Comment: I then tried to save the cursor position before write/read, but if a number gets added, the cursor is now on the left side of it, not the right.  
Next, I tried to keep the cursor on the right-hand side, which will let users type the number, but they can't edit properly from any other position, and this will be a nightmare when localizing for right-to-left languages.

So in the end, I just used OnValidated to check and re-read the value.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, second cup of coffee...

Here's a solution, but **is there a way to have it run real-time?** (as the user types) so they can see the error in their ways more immediately?

This technique updates the control's display after validation (when focus moves away from the control),

I used ComboBox.Validated event to trigger the control to re-read its value from the property.

Added:

```
comboBox_Speed.Validated += new EventHandler(comboBox_Speed_Validated);
```

And:

```
private void comboBox_Speed_Validated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   comboBox_Speed.DataBindings["Text"].ReadValue();
}
```